# Code crashes data structure manipulation

Tags: c++, memory-management, data-structures

In the following code below, for every Node contains a pointer to a pointer of all child nodes (of type Node)

In the line that crashes, I am allocating memory to the child_array and that returns a pointer of type node *.

Now in my actual node, I am setting the value of the child_array ptr-to-ptr to be

Can someone explain why this is crashing. Mathematically both sides of the equation are (node *).

One thing I can guess is that when I dereference child_array once to assign a node*, the derefenced value may point to garbage withoput being initialized. In that case how & when do I safely initialize it?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int val;
    int num_child;
    node** child_array;
};

node *head = NULL;

node* addelement(int parent_id)
{
    cout << " You are the child of " << parent_id << endl;

    int val, child_count;
    cout << "Enter value of element" << endl;
    cin >> val;

    cout << "Enter no of children" << endl;
    cin >> child_count;

    node* new_node = new node;
    if(new_node)
    {
        new_node->num_child = child_count;
        new_node->val = val;
        node *child_head = (node *)new node[child_count];
```

**cRASHING lINE below**

```
        *(new_node->child_array) = child_head; 
    }
    else
    {
        //assert(false);
    }

    for( int i=0; i<child_count; i++)
    {
        new_node->child_array[i] = addelement(val);
    }

    return new_node;
}

void printTree(node *head)
{
    if(head!=NULL)
    {
        cout << head->val << endl;
        for( int i=0; i<head->num_child;i++)
        {
            printTree(head->child_array[i]);
        }
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    head = addelement(0);
    printTree(head);
    cout << endl;
    cout << " Tree Elements\n";
    printTree(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Until you assign something to child_array, it is garbage.

Answer (score 0):

You dereference an uninitialized pointer and write to unallocated memory:

```
*(new_node->child_array) = ...
```

There is also a conceptual problem. Are you trying to create an array of `node`, or an array of `node*`?

Comment: I am trying to create an array of node*. But I think I can just use array of nodes.

Comment: If you're trying to create an array of `node*`, then `new node[child_count]` is incorrect.